# Prolog discarding permutation

Tags: prolog

I haven't been able to discard repetition permutations.For example, I want to get

```
?-permutation([1,2,1],L).
L = [1, 2, 1] ;
L = [1, 1, 2] ;
L = [2, 1, 1] ;
```

.
but i am getting

```
?-permutation([1,2,1],L).
L = [1, 2, 1] ;
L = [1, 1, 2] ;
L = [2, 1, 1] ;
L = [2, 1, 1] ;
L = [1, 1, 2] ;
L = [1, 2, 1] ;
```

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simpler way could be

```
perm_no_rep(L, P) :-
  setof(P, permutation(L, P), Ps),
  member(P, Ps).
```

it's almost ok:

```
?- perm_no_rep([1,2,1],P).
P = [1, 1, 2] ;
P = [1, 2, 1] ;
P = [2, 1, 1].
```

beware that will be `factorial(Num_Distinct_Elements_in_L) = length(Ps)` i.e. possibly very large lists.